# Opening About (App Name) with a button (Mac os x)

Tags: objective-c, macos, about-box

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a button inside of my mac app and when you click on it, it will open the About (App Name) window?

Hope it makes sense! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the `NSButton` to `File's Owner` and select `orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:` like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

Alternatively connect the `NSButton` directly to the following `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)theButton:(id)sender {

    [NSApp orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:self];

 }
```

Comment: Is it still possible when it's not in the MainMenu.xib? because it's in my other .xib I want it and it as a other files owner but uses the same menu bar. Sorry i forgot to mention that